# What is the smallest complexity class that this problem belongs to?

Tags: complexity-classes, polynomial-hierarchy

Given $d>0$ and a complete graph $K_n$ is there an integer $m<d$ such that there is an assignment of vectors from $\Bbb F_2^m$ to every edge such that sum of vectors in every simple cycle is not a $0$ vector?

What is the smallest complexity class does this problem belong to?

Comment: How is the input encoded? The input essentially consists of two numbers $d$ and $n$. Are they given in unary or binary? Moreover, for every $n$, there is a $d(n)$ such that the answer is $0$ for all $(\delta,n)$ with $\delta < d(n)$ and $1$ for all with $\delta \ge d(n)$.

Comment: @MarkusBläser What is smallest class if input is unary and what if it is binary (excellent comment though)? $d(n)$ exists is clear.

Comment: You should first figure out what $d(n)$ is, and only then worry about its complexity. Quite possibly it may given by a simple closed-form which would make it trivial to compute. As far as I can see, it is even possible that $d(n)$ is eventually *constant*: after all, $d=1$ is enough for *odd* cycles.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek finding $d(n)$ is what motivated me to this query. I know $(\log n)^2<d(n)<n\log n$ but pinning down it further looks hard

Comment: d(n) is recently proved to be linear in n. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.05773